# Running python code interactively from vim

Tags: vim, interactive

I have been using vim for coding in C and am currently switching to it for python as well.
I have the following line in my vimrc

```
autocmd FileType python map <buffer> <leader><ENTER> :w<CR>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

As my python files get more and more complicated, the time for processing the entire file takes longer as well. I was wondering if there is a way to keep my previous variables in memory and only run the additional lines of commands, just as I would in an interactive python session. Sending the full file to bash runs the entire script and clears all the memory.

```
text = read_file('my_file.txt')
text_index = index(text)
pattern = 'asdjhlsajf'
def search:
    ...
```

Basically, is there a way to send these commands line by line to an interactive python session from vim?

Comment: well I am no python so take my comment with caution. But I think you will need to have some instance of a python shell running constantly. There are some plugins that are doing that with ipython it seems: github.com/hanschen/vim-ipython-cell

Comment: If you're fine with using plugins, something like vim-slime that passes your data into a python REPL can work. The plugin mentioned by @DoktorOSwaldo looks good too

Comment: Take a look at [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime). You can run an interactive Python interpreter (ipython even better) and use slime to send snippets from Vim into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Doktor OSwaldo, @filbranden, amd @shaahiin suggested, vim-slime was a great choice (vim-ipython-cell has some additional scripts).

I downloaded the plugin using:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start
cd ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start
git clone https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime.git
```

Added the following to ~/.vimrc:

```
let g:slime_target = "tmux"
let g:slime_python_ipython = 1
filetype plugin on
```

Then used two tmux windows. One for vim, and the other for the iPython. using

> cntrl-c + cntrl-c

commands could be send to the iPython session.